# Swift 3 string insert

Tags: string, character, swift3

I have a label in which the text changes, based on the some context I need to insert a number "9" as a string into the labels string. So lets say I have "-102" I want to insert "9" into the string so it turns out like this "-9102", can someone some me how I would code that. The 
      label.insert("9", ind:2)
doesn't work.

Comment: NSLabel? NSTextField? UILabel? UITextField? Other? ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

label.insert("9", ind:2)

For index, you need to provide the index, not integer.

```
 // to insert at 0 position
let str = label.text!;
label.text!.insert("9", at:str.startIndex);
```

or

```
// to insert at 2nd position
label.text!.insert("9", at: str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)) ;
```

Comment: Thanks This worked I was stuck forever using swift2 syntax